# How to know the pressed key in the keyboard in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard, uitextviewdelegate

I am new to iPhone.
I'd like to know the key pressed in the keyboard, and instead of the letter of the key I'd like to insert another letter in `UITextView`.

So for this are there any methods which will be called when a key is pressed in the key board
and the methods in which we can change the letter of that key, which will be written to the `UITextView` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`UITextViewDelegate Protocol`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) provides a way of intercepting characters as the are typed using:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

at this point you can return NO and do your own text replacement.